# Why can't I see Pinia in Vue devtools?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, google-chrome-devtools, pinia, vue-devtools

I am developing an app using Vue 3, Vuetify 3, and Pinia, all of which I'm in the process of learning. I'm trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGC7aAC-3y8) to learn Pinia and at about 17:50, the presenter says to install Vue Devtools if necessary. I did that and was able to see a new Vue option added but when I clicked on it, I did NOT see Pinia despite the video showing plainly that my Pinia stores would be visible.

Why isn't this working? I'm using the version of Vue Devtools that is made by Vuejs.org, which is at version 6.50 and I have two Pinia stores but nothing to do with Pinia (aside from an acknowledgement that they were installed) appears in the Vue window of Devtools as you can see in this screen cap:

[image: Screen grab]

I'd appreciate if someone can tell me how to make Devtools show my Pinia store.

Comment: The one symbol at the top next to the arrows is a dropdown.  [Check for pinia there](https://i.imgur.com/0KjNtuG.png).

Comment: @yoduh - Thank you!! Now I can see my Pinia stores just fine :-)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and moving app.use(createPinia()) to bottom solved my problem.

that was the code when I cant see the pinia plugin at vue devtools

```
app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(VeeValidatePlugin)


app.mount('#app')
```

Then I moved the pinia down like this

```
app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.use(VeeValidatePlugin)
app.use(createPinia())

app.mount('#app')
```

after that pinia plugin appeared.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find that Pinia comes and goes from Vue Devtools: sometimes it's there and working fine, other times it's not there and no menu will make it appear. However, if you close and open CTRL-SHIFT-i or duplicate the tab and then do CTRL-SHIFT-i it may suddenly appear. I don't know if my browser or computer are wonky somehow or if there's a bug in the Vue Devtools code.

Comment: Confirmed, moving Pinia down helped.

Comment: Confirmed as of today. 

```createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(createPinia())
    .mount('#app')```